# App Engine Blobstore/ImageService - Served image has not the original size

Tags: image, google-app-engine, gwt, upload, blobstore

I managed to create the functionality to upload an image with the "gwtuploaded" to the app engine and store the image as an blob. My problem now is: The url that I get from `imagesService.getServingUrl(suo)` links to an image which is smaller than the image i uploaded. If i check the image in the blob viewer in the app engine console, it seems to have the correct size.

Why do I get a resized version of my image with the following code. Can I somehow retrieve the url to the full sized image?

My code looks like this:

```
public class MyUploadAction extends AppEngineUploadAction{

    @Override
    public String executeAction(HttpServletRequest request, List<FileItem> sessionFiles) throws UploadActionException {

        String imageUrls = "";

        // Image service is needed to get url from blob
        ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();

        // Get a file service -> write the blob
        FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();

        // Iterate over the files and upload each one
        for(FileItem myFile : sessionFiles){

            InputStream imgStream = null;
            // construct our entity objects
            Blob imageBlob = null;

            // Create a new Blob file with mime-type "image/png"
            AppEngineFile file = null;

            FileWriteChannel writeChannel = null;
            try {
                // get input stream from file
                imgStream = myFile.getInputStream();
                imageBlob = new Blob(IOUtils.toByteArray(imgStream));

                // create empty app engine file with mime type of uploaded file e.g.: image/png, image/jpeg
                file = fileService.createNewBlobFile(myFile.getContentType());

                // Open a channel to write to it
                boolean lock = true;
                writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, lock);

                // This time we write to the channel directly
                writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(imageBlob.getBytes()));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                // Now finalize
                try {
                    writeChannel.closeFinally();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            // Get the url from the blob
            ServingUrlOptions suo = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(fileService.getBlobKey(file)).secureUrl(true);
            imageUrls += imagesService.getServingUrl(suo);
            imageUrls = imageUrls.replaceFirst("0.0.0.0", "127.0.0.1");
            System.out.println(imageUrls);

        }
        return imageUrls ;
    }
}
```

Comment: By the code I assume you are testing this in your devel cluster? How are you determining that the image is served with the wrong dimensions, is it visually? Browsers resize images to show them completely on the screen? Are you appending any options to the generated url?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the original image back with ImageServices getServingUrl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783324/getting-the-original-image-back-with-imageservices-getservingurl)

Answer (score 1):

I tried and found that image service got a maximum image output of 1600x1600.
see here and search for 1600: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/

That applies even if you don't request for an resize.

To serve the image in original size, you shouldn't use the image service, just output directly from (e.g. blobstore)